# Raspberry Pi Kernel Compilation issue - fixdep permission denied

Tags: cross-compilation

I am trying to compile RPi kernel on Kali Linux. I have downloaded GIT & the tools-master from git. Can anyone help me in **resolving this issue** & **understand why this error comes**?

Below is the environment variable setup.

```
$ export CCPREFIX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
$ export PATH=/media/6605-F597/toolchain/tools-master/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/:$PATH
$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$CCPREFIX bcmrpi_defconfig
```

While running last command I get following error.

```
HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
/bin/sh: 1: scripts/basic/fixdep: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 126
make: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2
```

I tried goggling it but could not resolve this issue. I have this code in my vfat partition.

```
/dev/sda3 on /media/6605-F597 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=utf8,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks)
```

Comment: You sir need root permissions to run fixdep whatever your last command was, do $sudo command

Comment: I tried running as root also but it din't help. Then I moved my code to my home directory along with the toolchain & this this error was gone. But I can't understand this logic.

Comment: I am now facing some other error with my code & toolchain in my home directory. error is :- make: execvp: arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Permission denied

Comment: Man, when ever you see permission denied, on anything in mean you need root privilege. sudo that. (Super User DO...sudo)

Comment: I did use root permission & could not solve this issue, so i posted this question.

Comment: what is the output that file command gives on fixdep?

`file <path_to_kernel_source>/scripts/basic/fixdep`

Answer (score 1):

[`showexec`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) is problematic:

```
showexec
    If set, the execute permission bits of the file will be allowed only if      
    the extension part of the name is .EXE, .COM, or .BAT. Not set by default.
```

use `umask=000` (requires to `umount` and `mount`, remount doesn't help):

```
umount /dev/sdb1
mount -o umask=000 -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /media/sdb1
```

BTW I'd wouldn't clone / compile kernel on vfat (or other non-native fs).

Source: section "Mount options for fat" in [mount(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount), [wiki.linuxquestions.org](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/VFAT#Execute_files_on_a_vfat_partition).

Comment: A second reason never to compile on FAT filesystems is the time stamps are only two-second granularity, which breaks the working of *make*. Randomly. The MS-Windows make tool is aware of that. The Linux build of the tools is not.